# " ERROR: . " what does it mean?

Tags: sas

I got this error

```
ERROR: .
NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
```

Can anyone please guide me what exactly is this mean ?

Comment: You'll need to give some more details, including the code that generates the error...

Answer (score 4):

It's quite straight forward; SAS has received a critical error that cannot be overcome. The output of the datastep or proceedure will not have been created and you need to debug your progam. There are many possible causes for errors.

If you need help with this specific error provide more details &/or code.

Comment: +1 for answering the question in as detailed a fashion as possible given the question :)